# Target Natural Wonders

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing on a huge map and located a [`Natural Wonder`](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Natural_wonder_(Civ5)) very early in the game.  I now want to settle near it; however, I cannot for the life of me remember where it is exactly.  I uncovered a large portion of the map, so I prefer ***not*** having to tediously go through each tile to find out where it is.

Is there a way to target (center your screen) on the [`Natural Wonders`](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Natural_wonder_(Civ5)) you have found throughout the map? Or is there a list of discovered `Natural Wonders`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't anything quite as specific as what you are looking for. However, there is something that will make scanning the map easier. Try switching to strategic view (button in bottom right by minimap), where every natural wonder has a distinct and large icon. Using that you can quickly check the whole map and find the wonder much easier than in the normal view, since many of the natural wonders look a little too much like mountains in the standard view.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully someone stumbles across something, but until then I will use strategic view!

Comment: Shortcut key is F10